# Need to extract date after a certain section in a text file in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I have lots of text files. I need to extract date out of them. The required date actually is present in the text file in the format as follows:

1. random text here
2. **261 words 18 February 2008 22:25 Dow Jones International News DJI English**

/*This is a sample statement of line present in text file from which the date has to be extracted*/.

3. random text again

So now in this problem actually in a single text file there are many such sentences but always in this format.

A possible algorithm can be to select and display three words right after the "words" word in above sentence. Those three picked up will be the date. I needed a code in R for this.

Again to mention that the **data** in the text file is NOT in columns and rows but its **paragraph wise**.
It is **NOT** present in **bullet form** either. It is paragraph wise.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` out the lines starting with digits and then "words" (allowing for spaces), remove everything before "words" and convert to `"Date"` class.  Note that `as.Date` ignores any junk after the date.

```
# test data
Lines <- "random text here
261 words 18 February 2008 22:25 Dow Jones International News DJI English
/This is a sample statement of line present in text file from which the
 date has to be extracted/.
11 words 18 January 2009 20:20 Dow Jones International News DJI English
"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))

pat <- "^ *\\d+ words "
words.lines <- grep(pat, L, value = TRUE)
as.Date(sub(pat, "", words.lines), format = "%d %B %Y")
```

giving:

```
[1] "2008-02-18" "2009-01-18"
```

Comment: The code works fine. Thanks. Could you please explain the code? I am having troubles understanding it esp the use of textConnection and pat value.

Comment: `textConnection(Lines)` is just to keep the example self- contained.  In the real code replace it with something like `"myfile.txt" depending on the name of the file containing the text`.  `pat` is a regular expression (^ = start of line, space-star = 0 or more spaces, \\d+ = 1 or more digits) used by `grep` and `sub`.  See `?regexp`